# text manipulation and modification

Tags: text, awk

I am a beginner in scripting trying to learn from the scratch.
From a couple of questions I have posted, I was greatly benefited by this community and learned.
Although afraid to ask such a naive question here again, I dare to do it again here, so please help..

I have a file as:

```
A_B_C_D_E    
Q_W_F_R_S_G    
F_B_E_G_W    
T_Y_R_J_U
```

and I would like to cut the first and the second string delimited by '_" and output as:

```
AB [tab] A_B_C_D_E [tab] 0 [tab] 0    
QW [tab] Q_W_F_R_S_G [tab] 0 [tab] 0    
FB [tab] F_B_E_G_W [tab] 0 [tab] 0    
TY [tab] T_W_R_J_U [tab] 0 [tab] 0
```

I tried:

```
    cat file|tr "_" "\t"|awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {print $1$2,$1"\_"$2"\_"$3"\_"$4"\_"$5,"0","0"}
```

but this cannot capture the second line which has 6 strings, not 5..

I am so sorry to ask such a ridiculous question here..but I appreciate so much!!

Comment: Google `UUOC` wrt `cat file |...`.

Answer (score 2):

Most simply:

```
awk -F _ '{ print $1 $2 "\t" $0 "\t0\t0" }' filename
```

This tells awk to split lines into fields with `_` as delimiter, then print fields 1 and 2 (`$1`, `$2`) followed by a tab, followed by the whole line (`$0`), followed by `"\t0\t0"`, where `\t` stands for the tab character.

Or, if you prefer,

```
awk -F _ -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1 $2, $0, 0, 0 }' filename
```

It's a bit of a toss-up which is nicer. The first is simpler in terms of the mechanisms used, but I like the second a bit better because `$1 $2`, `$0`, `0`, and `0` are conceptually output fields (which makes the `,` notation feel natural) and it is (a little) easier to change the output field delimiter if it's only mentioned in a single place.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a simple substitution on individual lines, it's what sed was invented to do and does well:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^_]+)_([^_]+).*/\1\2\t&\t0\t0/' file         
AB      A_B_C_D_E       0       0
QW      Q_W_F_R_S_G     0       0
FB      F_B_E_G_W       0       0
TY      T_Y_R_J_U       0       0
```

but see @Wintermute's answer for a perfectly reasonable awk alterantive.

Comment: Thank you so much Ed! I will practice sed as well. learning, learning.. :-)

Comment: sed is simple, all you should use it for is `s/old/new/`. For anything else you should use awk so don't TRY to learn sed (it'll just come to you) get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins and focus on learning that and in the process you'll learn about the awk gensub() function which does what sed does.